# What Starts K8s Control Plane Support Services?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, systemd

I'm trying to understand how a kubernetes system bootstraps itself from the point of view of the programmer or systems engineer who *built* Kubernetes.

If I use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to start a kubernetes control plane, bash into the control plane container's process space, and look at the running processes, I see things like kube-scheduler, kube-controller-manager, kube-apiserver, kube-proxy, etc.

```
root@example-control-plane:/# ps -a -x | grep 'kube-'

# ...
523 ?        Ssl   23:55 kube-scheduler ...
561 ?        Ssl   41:50 kube-controller-manager ...
602 ?        Ssl  515:02 kube-apiserver ...
937 ?        Ssl    0:26 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy ...
# ...
```

However, it's not clear what initiated these proceses

If I look at the init services I don't see any obvious culprits.

```
root@example-control-plane:/# service --status-all
[ - ]  hwclock.sh
[ - ]  iscsid
[ - ]  kmod
[ - ]  nfs-common
[ - ]  open-iscsi
[ + ]  procps
[ - ]  rpcbind
[ - ]  rsync
[ - ]  udev
```

If I look at systemctl's status I can see the processes I'm interested in, (`kube-proxy` below)

```
root@example-control-plane:/# systemctl status    
● example-control-plane
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Sat 2023-03-04 23:09:24 UTC; 3 days ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─init.scope 
           # ...
           └─kubelet.slice 
             ├─kubelet.service 
             │ └─726 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock --node-ip=172.18.0.3 --node-labels= --pod-infra-container-image=registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8 --provider-id=kind://docker/example/example-control-plane --fail-swap-on=false --cgroup-root=/kubelet
             └─kubelet-kubepods.slice 
               ├─kubelet-kubepods-besteffort.slice 
               │ └─kubelet-kubepods-besteffort-pod01a9dfd5_1f7b_48ac_b0c0_1e95de67213c.slice 
               │   ├─cri-containerd-02186f62ce37bdaa8a2617461cae0b98a9b519ac5dbbdd203783db68f9bd07db.scope …
               │   │ └─937 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=example-control-plane
               │   └─cri-containerd-97d080ea62985fb006d261ae7d5243e243a28e65b438f93b5bcb3f33d9da8f59.scope …
               │     └─895 /pause
           # ...
```

but none of them seem to resolve back to a `.service` file, and the naming makes me suspect -- a program? -- is generating these slices and processes on the fly by interacting with the systemd API (also I'm a frozen cavewoman programmer when it comes to systemd, so if there's an obvious path here I'm probably missing it.)

So what's making sure these things start up?  Bonus points if you teach me enogh systemd so I could answer this myself.

Comment: Aside from this being blatantly [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a *programming* stack exchange, the kubernetes community is very good about developing out in the open and thus [one can see their systemd configuration easily](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/blob/v0.17.0/images/base/Dockerfile#L131). As far as the "big picture," one will want to read [their design docs](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/design/initial/#cluster-creation)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help mdaniel, but to your points 1. I'm a programmer investigating the implementation of K8s and its component parts, and those processes appear to be started programmatically. That feels on topic to this long time stack overflow user.  2. The systemd configuration you posted does not appear to invoke the commands I mentioned I'm interested in 3. The design document is known to me, but does not contain an answer to my question.  If I'm wrong on #2/#3 I'd appreciate knowing why.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and direct communication with the kind maintainers I learned a few things.

1. Each K8s distro deploys these helper services in a different way -- the K8s project itself does not provide a standard default distro.
2. The kind project, as of Mar 2023, uses a feature of the `kublet` app/service that will automatically load any valid configuration/manifest in the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` folder and create those pods.  This is how these helper services run in Kuberenetes itself as their own pods.